# Chebyshev inequality - why $n \leq \frac{||x||^2}{a^2}$ "tells us nothing"?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working through [Introduction to Applied Linear Albegra](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/vmls/) book which defines Chebyshev inequality as:

> Suppose that x is an n-vector, and that $k$ of its entries satisfy
> $|x_i| \geq a$, where $a > 0$. Then $k$ of its entries satisfy
> $x^{2}_{i} ≥ a^2$ . It follows that
>
> $${||x||}^{2} = x^{2}_{1} + · · · + x^{2}_{n} \geq {ka}^2,$$
>
> since $k$ of the numbers in the sum are at least $a^2$, and
> the other $n − k$ numbers are nonnegative. We can conclude that
> $k \leq \frac{{||x||}^2}{a^2}$.

It then claims that:

> When $\frac{{||x||}^{2}}{a^2} \geq n$, the inequality tells us
> nothing, since we always have $k \leq n$.

I am struggling to see why the fact that $k \leq n$ makes the inequality (from the 2nd quote above) "tell us nothing"? Could anyone explain to me what could be the logic behind this argument? If $\frac{{||x||}^{2}}{a^2} \geq n$, and $k \leq n$ then:

$$\frac{{||x||}^{2}}{a^2} \geq n \geq k$$

What **additional** information do we get from $\frac{{||x||}^{2}}{a^2} \geq k$ that we don't already have from $\frac{{||x||}^{2}}{a^2} \geq n$?

Comment: I'm wondering if when it claims "When $\frac{\|x\|^2}{a^2}\geq n$, the inequality tells us nothing, since $k\leq n$", *the inequality* the author is talking about is the first one, $\frac{\|x\|^2}{a^2}\geq k$.

Comment: I think so, I read it as 'the first inequality with $n$ plugged in for $k$'. Or do you mean they might have some completely different inequality in mind, that it's not present in the quotes I included?